# in my python code User Getting to Click Login button Twice, But user should only need to click the login button once to log in

Tags: python, authentication, streamlit

Hello fellow developers,

I am encountering an issue with my script and would greatly appreciate any assistance. My script runs successfully and executes the login() function without any errors. However, I have noticed that after entering my credentials and clicking on the login button, I am not able to log in on the first attempt. It requires me to click the login button twice before I can access my main application.

This behavior is unexpected and I am unsure how to resolve it. I have double-checked my code and confirmed that there are no syntax errors or logical issues that could be causing this problem.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue before? If so, could you please share your insights on how to resolve this problem? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or tips that could help me get to the bottom of this issue and achieve a seamless login experience for my users.

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.

```
import streamlit as st
import mysql.connector
import configparser
import hashlib
import time


# Define SessionState class to store state information
class SessionState:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.hash_funcs = {"_CodeHasher": lambda x: None}
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)


# Define a function to hash passwords
def hash_password(password):
    salt = hashlib.sha256(str.encode(password)).hexdigest()[:10]
    hashed_password = hashlib.sha256(str.encode(salt + password)).hexdigest() + ':' + salt
    return hashed_password


# Define a function to check if a password matches a hashed password
def check_password(password, hashed_password):
    try:
        stored_password, salt = hashed_password.split(':')
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return stored_password == hashlib.sha256(str.encode(salt + password)).hexdigest()


# Define a function to authenticate users
def authenticate(email, password):
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    query = "SELECT email, password FROM users WHERE email=%s"
    cursor.execute(query, (email,))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result:
        stored_email, stored_password = result
        if check_password(password, stored_password):
            return stored_email
        return False


# Define a function to create a new user
def create_user(name, email, password):
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    hashed_password = hash_password(password)
    query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(query, (name, email, hashed_password))
    mydb.commit()

    return cursor.lastrowid


# Read the configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Retrieve the database settings from the configuration file
database_user = config.get('database', 'user')
database_password = config.get('database', 'password')
database_host = config.get('database', 'host')
database_name = config.get('database', 'database')







# --------- User Authentication -------

# Read the configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

# Connect to the database using the settings from the configuration file
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(user=database_user, password=database_password, host=database_host,
                               database=database_name)

# Set the Streamlit page configuration
st.set_page_config(page_title="Chitti 2.0", page_icon=":guardsman:", layout="wide")


# Define the login page
def login():
    # Center the login form
    st.markdown("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Login</h1>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    email = st.text_input("Email")
    password = st.text_input("Password", type="password")
    # Apply styling to the login button
    st.write('<style>div.row-widget.stButton > button {width: 100%;}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
    if st.button("Login"):
        if email and password:
            with st.spinner('Logging in...'):
                user = None
                while user is None:
                    user = authenticate(email, password)
                    time.sleep(1)
                st.session_state.user = user
                st.success("Logged in successfully!")
    return None


# Define the signup page
def signup():
    st.header("Sign Up")
    name = st.text_input("Name")
    email = st.text_input("Email", key="signup_email")
    password = st.text_input("Password", type="password")
    confirm_password = st.text_input("Confirm Password", type="password")
    if password != confirm_password:
        st.error("Passwords do not match")
    elif st.button("Sign Up"):
        create_user(name, email, password)
        st.success("User created")
    else:
        return None


# Define the Logout
def logout():
    st.session_state.pop("user", None)
    st.success("Logged out successfully")


def main():
    # Display the main page if the user is logged in
    if not hasattr(st.session_state, 'user'):
        login()
        return None
    else:
        st.write("Main APP")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help me to Fix this.

Using Streamlit, for my UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an internal page jump operation, implemented in the script way

Re-execute the script after successful login

```py
def login():
    # Center the login form
    st.markdown("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>Login</h1>", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    email = st.text_input("Email")
    password = st.text_input("Password", type="password")
    # Apply styling to the login button
    st.write('<style>div.row-widget.stButton > button {width: 100%;}</style>', unsafe_allow_html=True)
    if st.button("Login"):
        if email and password:
            with st.spinner('Logging in...'):
                user = None
                while user is None:
                    user = authenticate(email, password)
                    time.sleep(1)
                st.session_state.user = user
                st.success("Logged in successfully!")

                st.experimental_rerun()
    return None
```